# ¿Como soliciono este error Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+?

Tags: android, facebook

Buen día, hace unos días abrí mi proyecto de Android studio y me encontré con este error
[image: Error al abrir el proyecto]

esto aparecio de la nada ya que todo estaba funcionando bien.

Pense que solamente debia dar click sobre "Install Repository and sync project" y todo se hiba a solucionar pero no pasa nada, no inicia el instalador de actualizaciones.

Realizando un seguimiento a las dependencias de mi .gradle llegue a la conclusión que este error desaparece cuando quito la dependencia al SDK de Facebook (compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') por esta razón creo que esta dependencia es la que me exige instalar la actualización

este es mi .gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'code.taxigp.com.usuario'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    compile 'com.github.anshulagarwal06:PasswordEditText:v1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.github.dakatso:livebutton:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ya tengo las ultimas actualizaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Como puedo solucionar este problema?

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Probaste pulsando instalar  Repositorio y Sincronizar?, por lo que veo en la imagen dice que tienes instalado el sdk hasta la versión 27.0.0 y tu proyecto requiere la 27.0.1

Comment: Si pero no pasa nada

Comment: Intenta utilizando esta dependencia `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'` y dinso que pasa.

Comment: Einer muchas gracias por la ayuda, el proyecto compilo correctamente, ¿donde encontraste esa dependencia?, yo busque directo en la información de Facebook y no encontré nada, ¿esta dependencia es mas antigua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se soluciono cambiando la dependencia de facebook por esta:

> compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:**4.28.0**'

donde se define la [versión del SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads).

y no usando el formato que indica la [documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started), que al parecer el formato es solo para instalar alguno de los [6 componentes del SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks):

```
implement 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'
implement 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
implement 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'
implement 'com.facebook.android:facebook-places:[4,5)'
implement 'com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:[4,5)'
implement 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[4,5)'
```